# Check if function is true without calling it

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, function, call

I have a function that I want to call conditionally depending on whether it's true/false:

```
If someFunction() = True Then
    someFunction()
    ' Other code here...
End If

Private Function someFunction() As Boolean
    MessageBox.Show("Function called!")
    Return True
End Function
```

Checking to see if the function is true, undesirably calls the function so the message box box is presented twice.

How can I check if a function is true without calling it?

Note: I need my function to return true/false in addition to the other code it runs.

Comment: If you find yourself in this dead-end then your function is doing too many things. Try to split the function in two logical parts, one that check the condition and one that execute the conditional code.

Comment: put the MsgBox in an IF statement so the stuff only runs if it needs to and skip calling it twice.  `If needsToDosomething Then DoSomething....`

Comment: You can't, and that's just plain common sense. You clearly cannot find out what it will return without calling it. Change your logic.

Comment: Your question shows a disturbing lack of logic

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle

Answer (score 2):

By definition you cannot!

You may need to split your operation into two parts:

- Function checkXX to see if something needs to be done
- Function do it, to actually do the work

Alternatively,
Simply call the function and have it do its work once, depending on the "true / false" condition you are testing for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very elegant work-around and I would still suggest what the others say (i.e. change your logic), but if there's REALLY nothing you can do to change it and your problem is just *undesirably call the function so the messagebox is shown twice*, you might think about controlling the parts of the function code with an if-block and a control variable:

```
If someFunction(False) = True Then
    someFunction(True)
    ' Other code here...
End If

Private Function someFunction(ByVal showMsg As Boolean) As Boolean
    If showMsg = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Function called!")
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Please note that I'm sticking to your need of not showing the message box twice, but the answer to your other question *is it possible to evaluate a function without calling it* is no, you should rather split the function into two logical parts as someone else already suggested you, for sake of a more functional and elegant code.